# How can you use ActionEvent e with key binding?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, key-bindings

When I first used ActionListener, it was with JButtons. We used to setActionCommand("blah") for every button. Then, in `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`, we used something that looked like this `if(e.getActionCommand().equals("blah")) //do something`. However, with key bindings, since I am using the same component, there is no point to setActionCommand. ActionEvent now seems useless. Can you set a key to an actionCommand?

Comment: You could use `KeyListener` instead.

Comment: An action can have a key combo. associated with it, and a [button can be constructed from an action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html#JButton-javax.swing.Action-). That answers your question as best I understand the question (which is 'not much').

Comment: `e.getActionCommand() == "blah"` And that is not how to [compare strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).